# Colocar função jQuery em botão

Tags: php, jquery, html

Preciso colocar uma chamada de função em botão de `submit`, que verifique se existe, pelo menos, um arquivo no banco de dados e caso não tenha não deixa a form ser submetida.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisará de uma chamada `AJAX` ao servidor para verificar se existe ou não a entrada no banco de dados. O retorno dessa chamada pode ser um `JSON` que indica que a entrada existe ou não.

Código genérico do que você pode fazer. Acredito que você consiga adaptar.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e){
    e.prenventDefault(); // previne form de ser submitado
    $.get(
        'controlador.php', // código em php que recebe chamada ajax 
        {
            data : dados // eventuais dados
        },
        function(resposta){
            if (resposta.temEntrada){
                $('#formId').submit(); // submita form de id `formId`
            }else{
               // faz outra coisa
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve ir via AJAX verificar se existe o registro no banco de dados. No retorno você submete ou não o formulário.

Ou você pode submeter, verificar, e se nao houver o registro você estoura uma exceção.

Existem várias formas de resolver seu problema, eu particularmente optaria pelo ajax. Enviava tudo via ajax.

Comment: um exemplo pratico de pelo menos um dos modos de se fazer é importante para o entendimento, até por que ele deve saber que tem que fazer isso, mas não saber em termos de código

Comment: Estou fazendo isso:

<input type="submit" value="Finalizar Cadastro" id="checa">

$(document).ready( function(){

 $("#checa").on('click',checaUpload(){
  var id_credor = $("#id_credor").val();
  alert(id_credor);

});

Só pra ver se o JQ ta pegando o valor, do campo, mas parece que não está funcionando!

Comment: Gustavo, seu código não parece executar quando clicado. O ideal é:

`$("#checa").on('click', function() { alert($("#id_credor").val()); });`

Comment: Fiz isso e não está barrando o envia da form

$(document).ready( function(){
 $("#envia").on('click', function(){
  var id_credor = $("#id_new_credor").val();
  $.ajax({
   url: "../php/checaUpload.php",
         type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
         data: "id_credor="+id_credor,
         error: function(data){
          var estatus;
          estatus = (data.status);
          if(estatus == 0){
           return false
          }
         },
  });
 });
});

Comment: Possivelmente não barra por que seu botao está como submit.

Coloque seu botao como type='button' e dentro da function coloca document.formName.submit trocando o formName pelo nome do seu form.